# how to align google geo charts legends in center

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I use google geo charts, It's legends take the default alignment. I don't have any options to align this legend. I want to align this legend into the center position.

```
var options = {};
```

I try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gdk4msx5/) JSFiddle

Comment: hi, any suggestions about this.

Answer (score 0):

there are no options to change the alignment of the legend on a GeoChart,
but it can be moved manually.

however, the chart will move it back to the original position on activity,
such as when the mouse is moved over a country.
in the case, a `MutationObserver` must be used,
to move the legend, each time it is drawn.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['geochart'],
  mapsApiKey: 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['Germany', 200],
    ['United States', 300],
    ['Brazil', 400],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 600],
    ['RU', 700]
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 500,
    width: 900
  };
  var container = document.getElementById('regions_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
    var xCoord;
    var xDiff;

    // move legend bar
    var rects = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(rects, function(rect) {
      if (rect.getAttribute('y') !== '0') {
        xCoord = (options.width / 2) - (parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('width')) / 2);
        xDiff = xCoord - parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('x'));
        rect.setAttribute('x', xCoord);
      }
    });

    // move legend labels
    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      if (label.getAttribute('font-weight') !== 'bold') {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
          if (label.textContent === data.getFormattedValue(i, 1)) {
            xCoord = parseFloat(label.getAttribute('x'));
            label.setAttribute('x', xCoord + xDiff);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    });

    // move legend indicator (triangle shown on hover)
    var paths = container.getElementsByTagName('path');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(paths, function(path) {
      if ((path.getAttribute('fill') === '#000000') && (path.getAttribute('stroke') === '#000000') && (path.getAttribute('stroke-width') === '1')) {
        var d = path.getAttribute('d');
        var coords = d.split(',');
        var x1 = coords[0].split('M');
        var x2 = coords[1].split('L');
        var x3 = coords[2].split('L');
        var d1 = parseFloat(x1[1]) + xDiff;
        var d2 = parseFloat(x2[1]) + xDiff;
        var d3 = parseFloat(x3[1]) + xDiff;
        d = 'M' + d1 + ',' + x2[0] + 'L' + d2 + ',' + x3[0] + 'L' + d3 + ',' + coords[3];
        path.setAttribute('d', d);
      }
    });
  });
  observer.observe(container, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });

  chart.draw(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```